# Can't npm start my React project with eslint dependencies

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I installed `eslint` in my react project to fix all the eslint errors. I fixed all the errors, however, I can't `npm start` the project. When I do that, I get this error, and some steps to uninstall all the eslint dependencies. I want to run the project with eslint dependencies.

Please let me know how to do this?

**Error Message:**

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
> likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
> locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
> dependency:
>
> "eslint": "^7.11.0"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
> automatically. However, a different version of eslint was detected
> higher up in the tree:

Comment: is your eslint version in your package.json 8?

Comment: @whygee I use `eslint 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you installed eslint@v8 and since create-react-app doesn't support it yet ([reference](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11374)) it causes this error.

Downgrading to eslint v7 should fix it.

Comment: I actually use `eslint 8` how can I downgrade it to 7?

Comment: change your package.json where you have `"eslint": "8xx"` to `"eslint": "^7.11.0"` and do npm install

Answer (score 0):

Create react app already comes bundled with eslint and by installing it in the project dependencies, you are in effect try to load in conflicting versions, you shouldn't need eslint inside of your own package.json.

**HOWEVER**

If you want to override eslint and start customising your react install you are more than welcome to eject (`npm run eject`), but bear in mind that ejecting your application will mean you will need to maintain dependencies going forwards.

You can read more about ejecting here - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/